# Where can I get a cached copy of a website from Google?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I've heard a lot about websites saved thanks to Google's cached copies of them. Where can I access these cached copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are several ways of doing this!**

[image]

**If you do a regular Google search**, in the above image, you can click on the **Green arrow** ([image]) and that will bring up a drop-down mean from which you can selected the **Cached** version.

[image]

Secondly, **if you are already at a website**, and you want to check its' cached version, then you can simply add **cache:** to the front of the URL, and....

- **press Enter** if your address bar allows Google searches (Like Chrome)

  OR
- **Copy and paste** the above full URL into the *Google Search*

Comment: Your `cache` tip doesn't work. Not everyone is using the browser you are or has the same default search

Comment: Yes, there is a slight mistake in what I wrote. I am correct in that you can use the "cache:<url>"; however, that is for any google search. In Chrome, you can use that in the address bar; however you  can always do it in a Google search...any browser.

Please revise your down comment.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise, I updated my post. Please read the above comment and my post

Answer (score 4):

Search for anything you want in Google then see there's a little down arrow (a triangle) exactly beside every URL shown in search results; click on it and select the option "cached" and the cached copy of that webpage will be shown.